# Calling php function in form action only if onSubmit js validation is true

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

Not sure where to go from here. Probably done a lot of mistakes but here goes.

I want my form to first call the js validation through the onSubmit and only perform the php function through the action if the validation becomes true... if that makes sense and if it is even possible?

My form:

```
<form method="post" name="editForm" action="edit_account.php" onsubmit="return checkForm();">
    <label>Change email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="changeMail" value="<?php echo htmlentities ($_SESSION['sess_email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
    <label>Change password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="changePass">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save changes">
</form>
```

Javascipt validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm() {

    var x = document.forms["editForm"]["changeMail"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid E-mail address");
        this.changeMail.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

PHP function:

```
function edit_account_update(){
     <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

and the if statement to perform the PHP function from the form action: I know this currently use $_POST['submit'] so the if statement always activates after submit, but I don't want that.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    edit_account_update();
}
```

Comment: Why not just halt submitting if the validation doesn't pass. You then don't end up with bad data and the user gets a better experience, being able to correct errors without having to retype everything! - Should also be noted that your edit_account_update() will result in a fatal error

Comment: If you are using a framework like jquery u can use just $.ajax to make a request to your php file. If you want to use native javascript without a library, use xmlhttprequest object.

Comment: One option is PHP+JS validation. Second (prefered) options is PHP validation thru AJAX

Comment: How do I halt the submit if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Yeah I've heard that ajax can do this though I wanted to do it without ajax at the moment if it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be seeing an error on this line - observe your developer console (F12):

```
this.changeMail.focus();
```

because your checkForm() function is called without any context, and so `this` will refer to the `window` object not the form.

You can bind the context in the `onsubmit` attribute using [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
onsubmit="return checkForm.call(this);"
```

Or (preferably) use unobtrusive JavaScript.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.forms["editForm"].onsubmit = checkForm;
};
```

With the above, the `checkForm` will automatically have the `this` context applied.

Comment: I dont get a error at that line. I have this same validation in another file and it works. :o

Comment: Worked great with the window.onload. Such a easy solution too. Great!

Comment: It might be hard to see the error because it will flash on and then the page will submit to the action (so only briefly on the console). Glad this solved it :)